# component.ts class gives an error when the return type is iActionResult

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am a bit confuse right now. Whenever i return  `void` from my controller class everything works fine.

**my controller.cs class.**

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpPut("[action]")]
    public void EditEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repo.edit(employee);
            _repo.Save();
           // return Ok($"update was successful for {employee}");
        }   
      //  return BadRequest("Something Went Wrong");

    }
```

**my service.ts class**

```
 updateEmployee(employee) {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
  return this._http.put('api/Employee/EditEmployee', employee, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
  })
})
```

}

**and my component.ts class**

```
onSubmit(employeeForm: NgForm) {
//console.log(employeeForm.value);
this._employeeService.updateEmployee(employeeForm.value).subscribe(
  success => {
    this.Message = "Record Uploaded Successfully";
  },

  err => this.Message = "An error Occurred"
);
```

the code example above works as expected and returns **Record Uploaded Successfully**

but whenever i change the return type in my **controller.cs** class to `IActionResult`,

```
   [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpPut("[action]")]
    public IActionResult EditEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repo.edit(employee);
            _repo.Save();
            return Ok($"update was successful for {employee}");
        }   
       return BadRequest("Something Went Wrong");
    }
```

it updates the record successfully in my database but returns **An Error Occurred** in my component.ts class

[this is it on github](https://github.com/tizah/NewApp)

i want to understand what is happening and why i am experiencing this error.

[Image when controller.cs file returns void](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nskMB.png)

and

[Image when controller.cs file returns IActionResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEsWs.png)

Comment: Can u please check response status in the network tab ?

Comment: Returns 200 status code at both instance, when its void and IActionResult. Check the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a json object from your controller.cs class not a string literal

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpPut("[action]")]
public IActionResult EditEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _repo.edit(employee);
        _repo.Save();
        return Json(new { Message="Update was successful!"});
    }   
   return BadRequest(new { Message="Something went wrong!"});
}
```